# Exporting a Google spreadsheet chart as a vectorial image (PDF, SVG, etc.)

Tags: images, google-apps

I am looking for a browser extension that allows the user to export a Google spreadsheet chart as a vectorial image (PDF, SVG, etc.).

It should work on Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X or Ubuntu. Any browser is fine.

As far as I know, Google spreadsheet offers no way to  export a Google spreadsheet chart as a vectorial image.

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any program so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.